# Hide a menu item for admin user

Tags: 6, routes

How can I remove a menu item when admin is logged in?
I used the following code but it doesn't seem to work.

`function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
     $items['item_x']['access callback'] = 'mymodule_menu_access_callback';
     $items['item_y']['access callback'] = 'mymodule_menu_access_callback';
}
function mymodule_menu_access_callback() {
  global $user;
  if ($user->uid == 1) {
    return FALSE;
  }
  return TRUE;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User 1 bypass access controls, so that wont work. You could have 2 menus as blocks and use the block system to control which to use.

You could also use theming/CSS to hide the menu.

Answer (score 0):

what googletorp says is true but even more generally, you can't remove permissions to anything in drupal once they've been granted to a user (and user 1 is given all permissions).

i guess it depends whether you're just trying to hide it from display, in which case what googletorp suggests will be sufficient, or if you're actually trying to revoke access to a url from admin users.

a simple workaround (in addition to the suggestions from googletorp) to stop admins visiting said page would be to create a redirect using Rules that sends users with the admin rule somewhere else on that page.

Answer (score 0):

You could assign a specific permission to the menu item, and then give that permission to a role that your non-admin users have.

$items['item_x']['access arguments'] = array('my special permission for this menu item');

hook_menu http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7

This will work, but keep in mind uid 1 (aka super admin) bypasses access control.